# Question about partition of open sets in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, set-partition

I have to prove that any open set $U \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is a countable union of disjoint limited rectangles.

I proved that it is a countable union of rectangles, the "expected classical" way, I guess: using rationals. However, how can I make the union disjoint ?

Is it true that any countable union of rectangles in $\mathbb{R^n}$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of rectangles? If not, can you give me a counter-example?

Comment: By "disjoint" do you mean that their interiors are disjoint?

Comment: Well in the exercise it just says disjoint. I thought it really means $A \cap B = \emptyset$

Comment: True for $n=1$, and that's all.

Comment: No connected open set is the disjoint union of two or more nonempty open sets. So not all of your limited rectangles can be open.

Answer (score 3):

Any open ball in the Eucledian norm is a counterexample if $n>1$.

Comment: That's a natural example, +1. Do you see an easy way to actually prove it is not a countable disjoint union of rectangles?